# Vim shortcuts to select and copy the current line without the next line

Tags: vim

I want to map the current behaviour of `V` to `vv` and have `V` copy the whole line except for the newline at the end. Same for `Y`.

Comment: What exactly is the question? To copy one line just use `yy`. If you want to remap `V` and `Y` then do so. It is not really clear where you need help here.

Comment: Could you please clarify your exact question here?

Answer (score 2):

You need these two lines:

```
nnoremap vv V
nnoremap V 0vg_
```